# Export mysql to a specific path via command prompt

Tags: mysql, database, export, command-prompt

I want to export my database to a specific path using command prompt, say, in D:\My Folder\Databases\mydatabase.sql. Is it possible ? If yes, can anyone tell me how ? Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > " D:\My Folder\Databases\mydatabase.sql" should do

Comment: It works when i pointed the address into disk C, but when I did the same to disk D it said "the device is not ready" and the file was not imported. I wonder why ?

Comment: you need to check the folder/permission

Comment: @Satya, It still says "the device is not ready", even though i have given all privileges to the system, user, authenticated user and administrator. I also ran the command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > " D:\My Folder\Databases\mydatabase.sql"` should do

Answer (score 1):

I have also got this error , Device is not ready , while taking mysql backup using mysqldump command ,    it got resolved , the problem is with your path used in backup command or the drive where u r trying to take backup ,

i was trying to take backup on D drive which is not present on my system , i changed it to E and it worked.

Comment: Yes, I never thought that I would forgot my disk partition name. The problem was already solved by the way :')